# Bind/Fail2ban how to reject requests from certain domain

Tags: bind, fail2ban, block, blocking

Today I got my VPS stucked.
Centos 7, 4 cores, Bind 9.11.
From ssh I got

> Message from syslogd@host at Jul 18 09:46:16 ...  kernel:NMI watchdog:
> BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 41s! [f2b/observer:1299]

From another ssh screen leaving `top` running I got at the end

> top - 10:06:05 up  9:22,  1 user,  load average: 101,26, 106,77, 94,46
> Tasks: 318 total,  80 running, 218 sleeping,   0 stopped,  20 zombie

From /var/log/messages I have several lines like these ones

```
Jul 18 09:44:04 host named[1078]: client @0x7fb37010e820 192.182.160.249#80 (domain.com): query (cache) 'domain.com/RRSIG/IN' denied
Jul 18 09:44:04 host named[1078]: client @0x7fb37010e820 192.182.160.249#80 (domain.com): query (cache) 'domain.com/RRSIG/IN' denied
Jul 18 09:44:04 host named[1078]: client @0x7fb37010e820 97.100.253.26#3658 (domain.com): query (cache) 'domain.com/RRSIG/IN' denied
Jul 18 09:44:04 host named[1078]: client @0x7fb37011cfc0 192.182.160.249#80 (domain.com): query (cache) 'domain.com/RRSIG/IN' denied
Jul 18 09:44:04 host named[1078]: client @0x7fb370100080 97.100.253.26#3658 (domain.com): query (cache) 'domain.com/RRSIG/IN' denied
Jul 18 09:44:04 host named[1078]: client @0x7fb370100080 192.182.160.249#80 (domain.com): query (cache) 'domain.com/RRSIG/IN' denied
```

After reseting the server it was all normal but after some hours problems came again.
At this time all is good but `tailf /var/log messages` outputs

```
Jul 18 12:33:13 host named[1017]: client @0x7fcde010e820 172.58.188.22#64587 (domain.com): query (cache) 'domain.com/RRSIG/IN' denied
Jul 18 12:33:18 host named[1017]: client @0x7fcde010e820 67.240.44.5#80 (domain.com): query (cache) 'domain.com/RRSIG/IN' denied
Jul 18 12:33:21 host named[1017]: client @0x7fcde010e820 172.58.188.22#64587 (domain.com): query (cache) 'domain.com/RRSIG/IN' denied
Jul 18 12:33:29 host named[1017]: client @0x7fcde010e820 172.58.188.22#64587 (domain.com): query (cache) 'domain.com/RRSIG/IN' denied
Jul 18 12:33:47 host named[1017]: client @0x7fcde010e820 67.240.44.5#80 (domain.com): query (cache) 'domain.com/RRSIG/IN' denied
```

More spaced in time requests so they don't hurt but after a while... who knows.
How can I reject incoming requests from this known "domain.com" (or others)?
This is a small budget server, cannot hire those services preventing DDOS attacks.

I followed these last [instructions](https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-block-a-domain-in-bind-dns-server-on-centos%20creating)
I created /etc/named/block and added a zone at /etc/named.conf

It worked, `tailf /var/log/messages` doesn't list those requests anymore, but I don't know if it is a good idea doing it in that way.

UPDATE: [image: screenshot]

Comment: Well, even your server gets 5 million requests, its just a bit of noise, to stop this kind of requests, you have to fix it via fail2ban instead of named

Comment: @djdomi I already have installed f2b from scratch. I don't know how to handle that issue with fail2ban. A webpage with 30 thumbnails produces a lot of requests in a short time. I added a screenshot of a crucial part of /var/log/messages.

Comment: I would suggest to enable rate limits and then use my regex for [fail2ban](https://github.com/djdomi/fail2ban-rules/blob/main/named/named-antispam/named-antispam.conf)

Comment: then update your question with this information what you have tried too. and also remember that there some standard rules like named-refused-tcp or udp

Comment: Soon as I can I will move to another vps and then follow your recommendations. There will be a delay. Thanks.